# How to get image URLs in different pages using a single WIKI api call?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

We can get text extract of different pages in a single wiki api call by using pipe character ( | ).

For eg : http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exlimit=max&explaintext&exintro&titles=Yahoo|Google&redirects=

By using this api call, we can get datas about Google and Yahoo in text format. Here we get datas of both Google and Yahoo in a single api call.

I want to get image urls of both Google and Yahoo in a single wiki api call.
Is there any method to get all image urls of different pages in a single wiki api call?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just switch `prop=extracts` to `prop=images`. Works exactly the same way:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Yahoo|Google&prop=images
```

The full documentation is here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties

To get the url of an image, use `prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url` for the corresponding file page.

Finally, you can combine it all in one single request, by using the `prop=images` result as a [generator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) for the `prop=imageinfo` call:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&generator=images&titles=Google|Yahoo!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some warning because you are missing the format=json. So the correct is

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&generator=images&titles=Google|Yahoo