# How to get image URL in wiki api?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wiki

When I call wiki APIs for accessing image URLs, I get image URLs like this,

```
File:Ad-tech London 2010 (2).JPG
```

How to get the correct URL of this file from wiki API?

Comment: Which is the API query you used that returned said "URL"? You might be able to use the current module as a generator and get imageinfo [within the same query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30779503/2683737).

Answer (score 16):

There's little documentation on image/thumbnail URLs besides [T153497](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T153497). You can use `Special:FilePath` and/or `thumb.php`:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Ad-tech_London_2010_(2).JPG
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Ad-tech_London_2010_(2).JPG?width=200 (to get a thumbnail of 200px width)
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/thumb.php?f=Ad-tech_London_2010_(2).JPG&w=200

Comment: Thanks for that. There is a bit of a documentation that I could find once you gave the direction: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Linking_to_files#Direct_links_from_external_sites

Answer (score 12):

You can get the proper URLs from an imageinfo query like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Test.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iilimit=50&iiend=2007-12-31T23:59:59Z&iiprop=timestamp|user|url
```

More info at [MediaWiki API Help](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bimageinfo).